# Vega-lite customize colors in grouped bar chart with multiple measures

Tags: visualization, vega-lite

I started with [this](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_grouped_repeated.html) vega-lite example from the gallery and now I'd like to customize this chart by changing the default blue and orange colors to custom color by RGB value. Is that possible with vega-lite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just set a scale.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "data/movies.json"
  },
  "repeat": {"layer": ["Worldwide Gross", "US Gross"]},
  "spec": {
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "field": "Major Genre",
        "type": "nominal"
      },
      "y": {
        "aggregate": "sum",
        "field": {"repeat": "layer"},
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title": "Total Gross"
      },
      "color": {"datum": {"repeat": "layer"}, "title": "Gross",
      "scale": {"range": ["#2a9d8f", "#e76f51"]}},
      "xOffset": {"datum": {"repeat": "layer"}}
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "mark": {"invalid": null}
  }
}
```